# Empire earth 2 crashes for windows 8.1

Tags: empire-earth

I tried to create a batch file I looked up in the Internet and it still doesn't work what is the problem?
I typed:

> taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe
>
> EE2.exe
>
> Start explorer.exe"

When I run it as administrator it opens up my computer
When I simply double click it a c:\ windows\system32\cmd.exe poped up and said that there has been an error  " invalid argument/ option - /F/IM
Type ' taskkill /?' "
What seems to be the problem and how can I possibly fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the newline after /IM.  Your batch file should look something like this:

> taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe
>
> EE2.exe
>
> start explorer.exe

Comment: That is exactly what I wrote. I edited my question. I am sorry. If there is any fix could you pls help!

Comment: This is what I get running that command`taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe`
`SUCCESS: The process "explorer.exe" with PID 576 has been terminated.`  Looking at your question again, it looks like you forgot a space between /F and /IM

Comment: Who could have known a single space can have such a devastating effect, thanks sommerjj, it works!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively Empire Earth 2 can be made to work on Windows 7-10 by installing the [unofficial patch](http://www.ee2.eu/patch/).  This has a number of tweaks but fixes the graphical issue that causes EE2 not to run on Windows 10.